# I messed up conda, commands not working on Mac

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter, conda, apple-m1

its my fist time im working with python on an apple product and outside of the anaconda ide....

I followed the instructions of

"18 Steps to install tensorflow_macos on the M1 MacBook (2020)" and it worked. It was working fine.

Later I tried to install Jupyter Notebook which did not work. I tried a lot and probably did a lot wrong.

I got some "killed" msg in the Terminal

Now Conda (Miniforge3) is installed but the commands are not executed, just ignored.

```
kleimie@Air-von-Andreas ~ % conda list
kleimie@Air-von-Andreas ~ % conda help
kleimie@Air-von-Andreas ~ % conda --version             
conda 4.9.2
```

I also can not activate the set environment

Does this PATH make sense?    `PATH=/Users/kleimie/miniforge3/bin:/Users/kleimie/miniforge3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: It looks like non of the Conda commands are working

Comment: Should the PATH read miniforge3 and not miniconda3? If you install miniconda3, then your path should contain the path to miniconda3 itself, to the miniconda3 Scripts directory and to the miniconda3 Library directory.

Comment: But I installed Miniforge3 and it was working until I did something wrong. One thing which I also noticed that the "(base)" is also gone when I open the terminal.

Comment: what happens when you issue `conda init` in the terminal? What happens when you issue `conda info --envs` in the terminal? Can you show the tree (that means the directory structure) you have in your miniforge3 directory?